# Let $(X,d) ; (Y,e)$ be two metric spaces ; can we define a metric on $X \cup Y$ whose restriction on $X$ is $d$ and restriction on $Y$ is $e$ ?

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $(X,d) ; (Y,e)$ be two metric spaces ; can we define a metric $\rho$ on $X \cup Y$ such that $\rho(x,y):=d(x,y) , \forall x,y \in X$ and $\rho(x,y):=e(x,y) , \forall x,y \in Y$ ?

Comment: Do $X$ and $Y$ have any points in common?

Comment: @MattSamuel : May or may not be

Comment: Can you unaccept my answer so I can delete it please? It's wrong.

Comment: @MattSamuel : I accepted , because I verified that if $X,Y$ are disjoint , then we can define $\rho$ to be $1$ for $x \in X$ , $y\in Y$ , but as you please , I have unaccepted

Comment: It may not satisfy the triangle inequality.

Comment: @MattSamuel : Ithink it does , I verified some cases , and I felt it was okay ... why do you think it may not hold ?

Comment: Consider $x,y,z$ with $x,z\in X$ and $y\in Y$. Then the sum of the distance from $x$ to $y$ and $y$ to $z$ is 2, while the distance from $x$ to $z$ can be anything.

Comment: @MattSamuel : True , hmm . So any further thoughts . I am stuck till now as well

Comment: See my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint, define a metric $r:(X\times Y\times [0,1])\times(X\times Y\times [0,1])\to \mathbb{R}$ by $r((x,y,z),(x',y',z'))=\max(d(x,x'),e(y,y'),|z-z'|)$. Choose base points $x_0\in X$ and $y_0\in Y$. Then if $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$ we define $\rho(x,y)=r((x,y_0,0),(x_0,y,1))$, and if $x'\in X$ and $y'\in Y$ define $\rho(x,x')=r((x,y_0,0),(x',y_0,0))$ and $\rho(y,y')=r((x_0,y,1),(x_0,y',1))$. This is essentially identifying $X$ with $X\times \{y_0\}\times \{0\}$ and $Y$ with $\{x_0\}\times Y\times \{1\}$, so it is easy to verify that this metric satisfies the conditions.